# Facing issue while deploying Logic App connector ARM template

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I am able to create logic app workflow in portal,I am deploying logic app with the sameARM Template automatically

but, after creating workflow it is showing as "Connector not Found" as shown in below image

[Issue Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNzhb.png)

I am getting this error while deploying logic app workflow using ARM template

Let me know if any additional information required

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please include ARM Template also to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Connector not Found" - looks like the connector that you are trying to use is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureloganalytics/#run-query-and-list-results-%5Bdeprecated%5D).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqGOE.png]

Refer further for the usage of the "[Run query and list result](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-monitor/logs/logicapp-flow-connector.md#add-azure-monitor-logs-actionWritten)"